# Limit Twitter Search to a particular list

Tags: twitter

I'd like to specify a Twitter list to search for a specified hash tag.

Searching by a hash tag is easy: http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23geocamsu will search all of Twitter for the #geocamsu hash tag. I'd like to limit that search to a particular list but do not see an option for doing so on their advanced search page.

Is there something I'm missing that allows for specifying a list?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter doesn't let you search within a list with it's search function. But you can achieve it the other way around. You can [fetch all the statuses](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/statuses) from a list in some interval, preferably using the `since_id` parameter, and search in those tweets. It's kind of hectic way, but the only way right now.