# Searching my Twitter lists

Tags: twitter, search

How can I search tweets among the ones that belong to tweeters in one of my [twitter lists](http://support.twitter.com/entries/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists)? I don't seem to find a tool to do it.

Maybe it's just me overlooking, but can you help me?

Comment: The [advanced search](https://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced) allows you to search the Tweets from specific people, but there's nothing about lists that I can see either.

Comment: It is not a web app but you need [Spaz](http://getspaz.com/) in your life, it does not search how you would like but it does filter.

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12361/limit-twitter-search-to-a-particular-list << Same question? Merge?

Answer (score 1):

TalkingPuffin allows you to load a list and then filter it - that might be what you are looking for. I am sure there are many other clients that can do the same.